# Visually slide down fixed element with items aligned at flex-end

Tags: css, flexbox, css-transitions, slide

I display an app drawer-like *component* in my mobile web app where I use bottom navigation icons with *more* which opens additional options.

#### Some options-drawer facts

1. Slides up/down into/out of the view
2. Has full screen height
3. Vertically aligns items at the bottom
4. Displays N options/per row (unlike attached image which only has one option per row)
5. Is placed within the same `position: fixed` container at the bottom of the screen as the main bottom navigation.

My options drawer should animate similar to what can be seen on this iOS animated GIF

https://jsfiddle.net/LL4dst15/

[image: App drawer]

### The problem

My drawer is using flexbox (as you can see from the example) where it aligns elements to `flex-end` on cross axis to display them at the very bottom. But the problem is the navigation container which is fixed positioned and has such `z-index` that it gets displayed over the content at all times.

#### `translateY` problem

If I use `translateY` the drawer actually slides in/out as it should, but drawer element's position doesn't change which means that navigation container still has the height of the drawer + bottom bar. This can be seen in my fiddle example on the left where the gray element is always seen. This would therefore cover my actual content so users would have difficulties interacting with it.

I could however use `pointer-events: none;` but I consider this a rather ugly hack that may have problematic browser support. So I would like to avoid it.

#### `max-height` problem

If I use `max-height` instead of transformations, then navigation container actually does resize when drawer resizes. The problem with this approach is that drawer doesn't seem to slide up/down, but rather *folds* as blinds... The reason is cross axis alignment to flex end. If I'd align to flex start then it would seem as if it's sliding out.

I was trying to resolve this one with auto margins, but couldn't seem to make it work, so that I would have flex start cross axis alignment but using auto margins to push content to the bottom of the drawer. No luck...

**Do you have any other suggestions** how should I do CSS so that my drawer would slide and my container would also resize?

Comment: Your code sample would be more accessible if you provided plain CSS (and within the question itself, as per SO guidelines). I took a shot, but was spending too much time compiling your code. Hope somebody else can help you. Good luck.

Comment: @Michael_B Why is that? You should be running the code (and changing it) directly on JSFiddle. No need to get it onto your local machine and compile it. JSFiddle precompiles SCSS to CSS when you run it... But it's true about source code. I'll add main excerpts. (**and btw**: changing this rather short SCSS file to CSS manually shouldn't take too much time either)

Comment: Tried to compile in jsfiddle and codepen.io. It didn't work. Non-standard CSS remained. Maybe I need to learn the functions better.

Comment: Why do you consider using `pointer-events: none` a hack? It's widely supported across all browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution with `translateY` and delayed `max-height`

Using animations has the drawback of having the animation of sliding out on load which should be separately handled by javascript, which I don't like. The solution to sliding out with `translateY` is to also resize it after `transform` has finished. Maximum height transition can be without animation afterwards, as long as it's done.

So on slide out instead of just doing the

```
transition: transform $duration; // plus opacity of you want
```

one should be doing

```
transition: transform $duration, max-height 0s $duration;
```

This will complete the Y translation normally and then also change element's height to 0, which will resize container accordingly which was the problem in the first place. Mind that immediate transition of `max-height` has time dimension `0s` instead of just a simple `0` which would be ignored by browser.

If animation is long enough for users to start clicking content while Y translation is in progress one can also set `pointer-events: none;` to container, but don't forget to set it to `auto` on child elements because this property is inherited.

That will be the optional solution to the problem.

Here's the [resulting JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LL4dst15/1/) with upper implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using css animation and the keyframes; [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5s1ax7Lc/)

There is only one issue remaining: the code also runs when you load the page. This could be easily fixed with some jQuery.

Short version of what I did: I animated the transform: translateY() to get the effect you want, then in the last % of the animation I set your max-height to: 0vh. Personally I would prefer to do this with jQuery, but you wanted a css solution, so here you go.

Here is the code (The css is a bit messy now with all the outcommented things, but cleaning it up is your job) :

**html**

```
Click any bottom bar item to toggle options drawer
<nav>
  <ul class="bottom-nav">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="extras" label="Uses 'translateY' to slide drawer">
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<nav>
  <ul class="bottom-nav">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="extras" label="Uses 'max-height' to slide drawer">
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
    <li>Option</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**css**

```
html, body {
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #fcc;

  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  }

  @mixin drawer() {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-start;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
    overflow: hidden;
    &:before {
      content: attr(label);
      position: absolute;
      margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
      color: #999;
      font-size: 0.8125rem;
      font-style: italic;
    }
    li {
      flex-basis: 25%;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1rem 0;
      &:hover {
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
      }
    }    
  }

  .bottom-nav {
    @include drawer();
    order: 1;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .extras {
    @include drawer();
    order 0;
    z-index: 0;
    /* 100vh   = full height
     * 3.25rem = bottom nav bar (2×1rem padding + 1.25 line height)
     * 1.25rem = top text line height
     * 20px    = navigation fixed position bottom offset
     * 2px     = navigation container top and bottom border
     */
    height: calc(100vh - 3.25rem - 1.25rem - 20px - 2px);
    /*transform: translateY(100%);*/
    /*transition: transform 1s, opacity 0.5s;*/
    animation: closedrawer 10s forwards;
  }
  &.open {
    .extras {
      /*opacity: 1;*/
      animation: opendrawer 10s 1 forwards;
      /*transform: none;*/
      /*transition: transform 1s, opacity 0.5s 0.25s;*/
    }
  }

  + nav {
    left: 320px;

    .extras {
      /*transform: none;
      max-height: 0;
      transition: max-height 1s, opacity 0.5s 0.25s;*/
    }

    &.open {
      .extras {
        /*max-height: 100vh;
        transition: max-height 1s, opacity 1s;*/
      }
    }
  }
}
@keyframes opendrawer {
    0% {transform: translateY(100%); opacity: 1;}
    99% {background-color: blue; transform: translateY(0%); max-height: 100vh;}
    100% {background-color: blue; transform: translateY(0%);max-height: 100vh;opacity:1;}
}
@keyframes closedrawer {
  0%{transform: translateY(0%)}
   99% {background-color: red; transform: translateY(100%);max-height: 100vh; opacity: 1;}
    100% {background-color: red; transform: translateY(100%); max-height: 0vh; opacity: 0;}
}
```

**javscript**

```
$(function(){
    $(".bottom-nav li").click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
$(this).closest("nav").toggleClass("open");
  })
})
```

Comment: That was one of my possible ways of doing it but for the same reason (using additional script) I discarded the idea. But it got me thinking about the final state of max-height. so I eventually came up with a very similar solution to original one I only added the transition for `max-height 0s $duration` which basically delayed the transition of max height until other transitions completed and then resized it to 0 without any transition (0s).

Answer (score -1):

You should add the code below to your `.extras` class after the `drawer()`.

```
li {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
}
```

The JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/k9apwnsq/2/

Comment: *WTF Fiddle with checkboxes?* But otherwise this is not the solution I'm looking for as my options should still display in columns. The attached image was jut a demonstration of the drawer container that overlays content and shows what kind of sliding I want. My Fiddle example options are all positioned **exactly** how they should be. **The problem is** (as clearly explained in the question): With either drawer container not being resized so it keeps overlaying content or drawer not visually sliding out when being resized to zero height.

Comment: ...which does what differently than my original code? Both drawers still work **exactly** the same.